# Two vertically aligned views start differently when their shared parent view embedded in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have two table views within a view controller, and the view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

I have added the following constraints vertically, and I expect the two table views start at the same point, near the bottom of the navigation bar.

```
constraints.append(t1.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0))
constraints.append(t1.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -8.0))
constraints.append(t2.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.topAnchor))
constraints.append(t2.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.bottomAnchor))
```

However, it turns out the table view `t1` starts much lower than the table view `t2`, the latter of which starts near the bottom of the navigation bar as expected.

Why does this happen? How to fix this?

---

#### UPDATE

Constraints:

```
t1.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
t2.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

t1.dataSource = self
t2.dataSource = self

self.view.addSubview(t1)
self.view.addSubview(t2)

t1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
t2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

constraints.append(t1.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0))
constraints.append(t1.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -8.0))
constraints.append(t2.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.topAnchor))
constraints.append(t2.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.bottomAnchor))

constraints.append(t1.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0))
constraints.append(t2.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0))
constraints.append(t2.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0))
constraints.append(t1.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t2.widthAnchor))

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)
```

Data Sources:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Start"
    return cell
}
```

Unexpected Alignments:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just tried to replicate the issue.
The table views get perfectly aligned if I use the code below. Just added the constraints in the view controller.

```
t1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
t2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

view.addSubview(t1)
view.addSubview(t2)

t1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
t2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addConstraint(t1.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0))
view.addConstraint(t2.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0))

t1.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: t1, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100.0))
t2.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: t2, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100.0))


view.addConstraint(t1.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0))
view.addConstraint(t1.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -8.0))
view.addConstraint(t2.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.topAnchor))
view.addConstraint(t2.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.bottomAnchor))
```

Just gives me this layout:

[image]

Maybe you can give more insights into your whole layout code?

**UPDATE**

After investigating the issue with your provided layout code:
The table views are layouted exactly as expected. The problem is with the
`contentInset`.

Add this for some console logs:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print("Insets t1 -> \(t1.contentInset)")
    print("Insets t2 -> \(t2.contentInset)")
 }
```

This prints out:

```
Insets t1 -> UIEdgeInsets(top: 64.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
Insets t2 -> UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

There is an option in Interface Builder for your view controller named *Adjust Scroll View Insets*. Disable it (or use `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` in code).

In general table views (as can be seen in table view controllers) go under the navigation bar (so you get the blurring scroll effect...) but the content inset is set so that your first cell is below the navigation bar.
To avoid this behavior when referencing the top layout guide you have to disable this option. The other table view is not affected because it only references the layout constraints from the other one.

It is always very helpful to color the views, so you can see if misalignments come from your layout code or any other side effect. (Or use the view debugger from Xcode)

So after setting the flag it gets from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Cheers
Orlando

Comment: I think my code looks like yours. Have you tried Table View?

Comment: The red and the blue views are table views. I will try again with your sample code and post the results...

Comment: I updated my answer - may you have a look and give some feedback if it helped? Cheers!

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if that solved your problem so other users can see this.

Comment: I am not near my Macbook. I have already upvoted. I will be accept an answer as soon as I get a field test.

Answer (score 1):

Modify one line code would resolve it.

Replace

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)
```

with

```
self.view.addConstraints(constraints)
```

I think you don't understand the concept of [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) completely.

*UPDATE:*

Sorry about that I did't mean to the UINavigationController.
UIViewController defaultly adjust scrollview's inset, you can prevent it via **automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false**.

BTW, you can use Mansory or Purelayout to set constraints easily.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

var t1: UITableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Plain)
var t2: UITableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Plain)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This line is the point.
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit(){
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor .whiteColor()
    t1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    t2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    view.addSubview(t1)
    view.addSubview(t2)

    t1.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    t2.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    t1.dataSource = self
    t2.dataSource = self

    self.view.addSubview(t1)
    self.view.addSubview(t2)

    t1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    t2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    constraints.append(t1.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0))
    constraints.append(t1.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -8.0))
    constraints.append(t2.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.topAnchor))
    constraints.append(t2.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.bottomAnchor))

    constraints.append(t1.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0))
    constraints.append(t2.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0))
    constraints.append(t2.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t1.trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0))
    constraints.append(t1.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(t2.widthAnchor))

    view.addConstraints(constraints)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Start"
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek Sorry, I forget to embed the ViewController in NavigationController. See my update.